# Sick LMS100 Scan to Scan object filtering

Tags: ros, laser-filters, collision-object, sicklms

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone ever done scan to scan object filtering/comparing?  I want to use it to eliminate false positives.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28454/sick-lms100-scan-to-scan-object-filtering/) by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Occupancy grids are one way to do that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rplankenhorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1757/rplankenhorn/) on 2012-02-27**:
Would this work for really small objects?  I kind of want to filter really small objects out and only react to bigger objects.  (Objects less than 2cm wide.)

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-02-27**:
It works with the persistence of objects, not their size. Maybe not good for your application.